# Does JavaScript have to be enabled to play embedded video?

Tags: javascript, video

In order to view an embedded video on a web-page, is it absolutely necessary to have javascript 
enabled - assuming the web page is *not* in the latest HTML5 format and hence has none of 
the newer  type tags?

I have noticed that YouTube does not work with JS disabled and I was wondering
whether it was a conscious decision on YouTube's part to work only with JS enabled or
did they really have no choice.

Comment: No. Some Flash video players work without JavaScript enabled. But why don't you try it instead?

Answer (score 2):

The embed code for YouTube is basically an iframe that links to a normal HTML page that uses JavaScript to load in the video you want to see.

In general, you can view video without JavaScript enabled. Most videos are played through Flash, which you can include directly into your page with either an object tag or an embed tag.

There are libraries, such as SWFObject that will put those players into your page for you, but do so through the use of JavaScript. If you want to use a library like that, you will need JavaScript enabled.

Also, if your browser does support HTML5, you can load video directly into the page with the video tag, without the need of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube wants you to have Javascript enabled to deliver advertising.

The player you want to use to embedd the video will tell you if Javascript has to be enabled or not.

Most of the Flash based players work without Javascript enabled, some other don't.

If you are going to embedd a QuickTime video, you don't need to have Javascript enabled to play it